# How to reject uppercase characters in a version number using egrep?

Tags: grep

I have version numbers that look like this:

```
11.22.33
11.22.33-alpha
11.22.33-beta
11.22.33-beta2
```

But I need to reject versions with uppercase characters, e.g.

```
11.22.33-ALPHA     (bad uppercase)
11.22.33-alpha-1   (bad char '-')
```

*I must use egrep.*

Here's an example in bash

```
version=11.22.33-BETA
result=$(echo $version | egrep "[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+(-[0-9a-z]+)?"); echo $result

if [[ -z $result ]]; then
   echo "BAD version!!!"
else
   echo "Good version."
fi
```

This code doesn't work and outputs "BAD version", with result containing "11.22.33-BETA".
What do I need to change?

Comment: well, as you are using -z anyways, maybe you can go with =~ (does not use any command at all)
`if [[ "$version" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+(-[0-9a-z]+)?$ ]]; then echo "Good version"; else echo "Bad version"; fi`

Comment: Also, your code sample has a syntax error. I think you meant following:

`"([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+(-[0-9a-z]+)?)");`

Comment: @MasterYoda Well spotted. Had an extra bracket within the egrep call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`egrep` has been deprecated.

You may use this regex in `grep -E`:

```bash
grep -E '^[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+){2}(-[a-z]+[[:digit:]]*)?$' file

11.22.33
11.22.33-alpha
11.22.33-beta
11.22.33-beta2
```

Note use of anchors and quantifiers.

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[[:digit:]]+`: Match 1+ digits
- `(\.[[:digit:]]+){2}`: Match dot followed by 1+ digits. Repeat this group 2 times
- `(`: Start a group

  - `-`: Match a `-`
  - `[a-z]+`: Match 1+ lowercase letters
  - `[[:digit:]]*`: Match 0 or more digits
- `)?`: End group. `?` makes this optional match
- `$` End

---

You `bash` script could be like this using `-q` (quiet) option in `grep`. Note how we avoid creating a shell variable to store output of `grep`.

```bash
if grep -qE '^[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+){2}(-[a-z]+[[:digit:]]*)?$' <<< "$version"
then
   echo "Good version."
else
   echo "Bad version."
fi
```

Comment: That's very elegant! I like that very much.

Comment: I have never come across the '<<<' before. Does that have some name ?

Comment: Yes that is called here-string in bash